# Vb net Or logic is not working

Tags: vb.net

I want to permit my user to save data if he has given 11 characters or 17 characters in the textbox.
I have written this code for my vb net form input. But this logic is not working. if i remove the Or condition than this code works for 11 characters.
But i want to implement for 11 and 17 characters both.

```
If (txtSSN.Text.Length <> 11 Or txtSSN.Text.Length <> 17) Then
    MessageBox.Show(" National ID should be 11 or 17 characters!!",
                    "Saving Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    txtSSN.Focus()
    Return False
End If
```

Comment: since it's <> you want And not Or because not(A or B) == not(A) AND not(B)

Comment: I implemented this logic but its not working.

Comment: Please edit your question and show how you implemented the _new_ logic.

Comment: If Not (txtSSN.Text.Length = 11 And txtSSN.Text.Length = 17) Then

Comment: You had to choose either `If Not (txtSSN.Text.Length = 11 Or txtSSN.Text.Length = 17) Then` or `If (txtSSN.Text.Length <> 11 And txtSSN.Text.Length <> 17) Then`

Comment: @T.haque Please don't post code into comments. Edit the question. Your second logic requires the Length to be 11 and 17 at the same time, which will never be true.

Comment: Someone has given you a good answer to your specific problem, for future reference check out truth tables, from someone that struggles visualising boolean logic they'll help you out, [Try this](http://turner.faculty.swau.edu/mathematics/materialslibrary/truth/)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am new in this community that's why i made this mistake

Answer (score 6):

These three examples will work:

```
If Not txtSSN.Text.Length = 11 And Not txtSSN.Text.Length = 17 Then
    MessageBox.Show("National ID should be 11 or 17 characters!!",
                    "Saving Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

---

```
If txtSSN.Text.Length <> 11 And txtSSN.Text.Length <> 17 Then
    MessageBox.Show("National ID should be 11 or 17 characters!!",
                    "Saving Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

---

```
If Not (txtSSN.Text.Length = 11 Or txtSSN.Text.Length = 17) Then
    MessageBox.Show("National ID should be 11 or 17 characters!!",
                    "Saving Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. Your solution worked for my code